# Python - Working on 2.7 but error on 2.6

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a webapp on Django, but I'm getting an error on version Python 2.6.6, but it is working fine on 2.7

```
def check(attribute):
   global rates
   if (attribute.temperature_value < rates[0] or 
       attribute.temperature_value > rates[1] or 
       attribute.heartbeat_value<rates[2] or 
       attribute.heartbeat_value>rates[3]):
      return True
   else:
      return False
```

Django debugger is showing that there's a syntax error.

Also, if I try to remove the function I get another error in on another line saying

```
EOL while scanning string literal (views.py, line 109)
```

on Line 109:

```
data = \
  DataPool(
    series=
    [{'options': {
     'source': values},
       'terms': [
        'current_time',
        'temperature_value',
        'heartbeat_value']}
    ])
```

Thanks for your help.

Traceback:

```
File "/home/innovo/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  101.                             request.path_info)
File "/home/innovo/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  300.                     sub_match = pattern.resolve(new_path)
File "/home/innovo/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in resolve
  209.             return ResolverMatch(self.callback, args, kwargs, self.name)
File "/home/innovo/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in callback
  216.         self._callback = get_callable(self._callback_str)
File "/home/innovo/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py" in wrapper
  27.         result = func(*args)
File "/home/innovo/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py" in get_callable
  92.                 lookup_view = getattr(import_module(mod_name), func_name)
File "/home/innovo/.local/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py" in import_module
  35.     __import__(name)

Exception Type: SyntaxError at /
Exception Value: EOL while scanning string literal (views.py, line 114)
```

Comment: Can you show both of the full tracebacks?

Comment: As a note, it's a bad sign to see a function working on globals - pass in the reference to `rates` as a parameter instead. You can also simplify `if x: return true; else: return False` to `return x`.

Comment: There should be no difference in how string literals work between 2.6 and 2.7 as far as I am aware, so I'm a bit skeptical to the problem description.

Comment: Traceback added @DavidRobinson.

Comment: your problem might be in non-terminated string literal in the code *before* 114 line in views.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write it like this:

```
def check(attr):
    temp, pulse = attr.temperature_value, attr.heartbeat_value
    def check_range(value, low, high):
        return value < low or value > high
    return check_range(temp, rates[0], rates[1]) or \
        check_range(pulse, rates[2], rates[3])
```

Only the trailing backslash is necessary to solve your problem, though.

Not sure what your other problem is. This works fine:

```
class DataPool(object):
    def __init__(self, series):
        self.series = series

values = list(range(5))

data = \
  DataPool(
    series=
    [{'options': {
     'source': values},
       'terms': [
        'current_time',
        'temperature_value',
        'heartbeat_value']}
    ])
```

BTW, this code:

```
def check_range(value, low, high):
    return value < low or value > high
```

could also be:

```
def check_range(value, low, high):
    return not (low <= value <= high)
```

Comment: The first problem got solved :) thanks:) I'm checking the second problem.

Comment: You could use `return (check_...)` instead of `return ...\ `. Also `check_range()` definition can be moved to a global level